# XSLT to HTML for below case

Tags: html, xslt

I'm practicing XSLT and trying to achieve below scenario using XSLT. Please kindly help :-)

I have below input XML:

```
<Items>
<item><lineType>STX</lineType></item>
<item><lineType>STZ</lineType></item>
<item><lineType>STY</lineType></item>
<item><lineType>STY</lineType></item>
<item><lineType>STZ</lineType></item>
<item><lineType>STX</lineType></item>
</Items>
```

I want to display above XML as below HTML table format:

Example:

```
 Banner - 1
  STX
  STX

 Banner - 2
  STY
  STY

 Banner - 3
  STZ
  STZ
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following XSLT-2.0 code will satisfy your needs:

```
<?xml version="2.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />                <!-- remove spaces between elements -->

    <xsl:template match="Items">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="item" group-by="lineType">
            <xsl:sort select="lineType" />          <!-- sort output alphabetically -->
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('Banner - ',position(),'&#xa;')" />
            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()"> <!-- iterate over the elements of the current group -->
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,'&#xa;')" />
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

On the other hand an XSLT-1.0 way is the following template applying the concept of `Muenchian Grouping`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="unique" match="item" use="lineType" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="Items">
        <xsl:for-each select="item[generate-id() = generate-id(key('unique',lineType)[1])]">
            <xsl:sort select="lineType" />
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('Banner - ',position(),'&#xa;')" />
            <xsl:for-each select="key('unique',lineType)">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,'&#xa;')" />
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**The output in both cases is:**

```
Banner - 1
STX
STX
Banner - 2
STY
STY
Banner - 3
STZ
STZ
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for help sir !! Can this same be done in XSLT 1.0 since the XSLT engine run by my tool doesn't support 2.0 yet !!    xsl:for-each-group  is not working in my XSLT processor .. ! Thanks a lot in advance .. :-)

Comment: Yes. It can be done by using a concept called [`Muenchian Grouping`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Muenchian+Grouping). It includes using an `xsl:key` for ordering the enitities. There are _A LOT_ of examples on SO how to realize this.

Comment: Yeah .. "Muenchian Grouping"  with this word, i could see lot of sample for same .. in same stackoverflow.Thanks a lot for pointers sir !! Appreciate your quick response.

Comment: I added the XSLT-1.0 way of solving the task.